# C++ code cout printing rather then waiting for it to be used in string

Tags: c++

```
/*
 * hello_world.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Feb 21, 2017
 *      Author: George Lutas
 */

#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin>>ch; }

int main()      //C++ programs start by executing the function main
{
    cout << "George 17\n";
    string first_name = "George";
    int age = 17;
    cin >> first_name >> age;
    cout << "Hello," << first_name << "(age" << age << ")" << endl;
}
```

This is my code. What am I missing here. The goal of the code is to output, "Hello, George (age 17)". So, how do I get it to read that instead of, "George 17"? Also, I know I don't have std_lib_facilities.h installed. That is on purpose. I'm fairly sure (by the fact that no errors are showing up) that I have the libraries I need loaded.

Comment: ````cin```` is not attached to ````cout````. You are essentially writing out "George 17" to terminal  and then blocking on keyboard input.

Comment: @mascoj To extend: At least use `<< std::flush` to force output to the terminal.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- no, `std::flush` is not needed. `std::cin` and `std::cout` are tied, so calling a stream extractor on `std::cin` will flush `std::cout`.

Comment: Of course it's printing. That's what you have instructed it to do in the very first line. If you don't know what `cout << "George 17\n";` does why did you put it there?

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyse your `main` function:

```
cout<<"George 17\n";
```

This line prints `"George 17"` and switches to a new line.

```
string first_name="George";
int age=17;
```

This defines a string variable `first_name` initialized to `"George"` and an integer variable `age` initialized to `17`.

```
cin>>first_name>>age;
```

This reads input of type `string` and `int` (in this order) and saves it to `first_name` and `age`. It will not prompt you for input. (You would have to implement that using `cout`.) It simply waits for you to provide input. This may look to you like the program is finished. But it is not.

```
cout<<"Hello,"<<first_name<<"(age"<<age<<")\n";
```

This line will finally print your expected output.